# TableLayout alignments, so so close

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablelayout, xml-layout

I've finally switched to using a TableLayout, and it has proved to be the most successful. However, I can't get things to align correctly, despite my attempts to use `gravity`.

Code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TableLayout
android:id="@+id/background"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:minHeight="52dp" >

<!-- My pic row -->
<TableRow
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/myPicture"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:maxHeight="48dp"
    android:maxWidth="48dp"
    android:minHeight="48dp"
    android:minWidth="48dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

</TableRow>


<!-- Contact row -->
<TableRow
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/contactPicture"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:maxHeight="48dp"
    android:maxWidth="48dp"
    android:minHeight="48dp"
    android:minWidth="48dp" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/holder"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</TableRow>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/body"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textColor="@color/textColorReceived" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="-3dp"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="3dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:textColor="@color/dateColorReceived"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/media"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <View
          android:id="@+id/gifView"
          android:layout_width="200dp"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:padding="10dp"
          android:visibility="gone" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/date"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
    android:gravity="bottom|center"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
    android:textColor="@color/dateColorReceived" />

  </TableLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

It's current state

[image: screenshotOfCode]

This is so close to what I wish to achieve. I just need the `@+id/contactPicture` (the red guy) to be to the left of the `@+id/body` (the text); this goes for my picture, `@+id/myPicture`, except it needs to be on the right of the `@+id/body` text. I don't know why the `gravity` and `layout_gravity` aren't working.

I'm really close to perfecting this layout; I've been working almost 12 hours on this layout today, and probably far more than that if you total up this week's work. I really appreciate any and all help.

**This is what I'm going for**

[image: screenshot2]

Comment: Little confused on what you're looking for... could you clarify with a picture or words?

Are you trying to get all pictures to be displayed to the left of the text?

Comment: @Mr_Skid_Marks I'm looking to get the red picture on the left, with the body text to the right of it. I'm also looking to get the picture of me (the human) to the right, with that body text to the left of me. This is a texting app--trying to stagger the text. Which, right now--it is. Only thing that isn't working is where the two contact pictures are. The text needs to be next to them--not below the picture.

Comment: @Mr_Skid_Marks Here is a picture of where the images need to go. The red one needs to go down, but the text needs to be to the right of the image.[ScreenshotOfDesiredEffect](http://i.imgur.com/zGuXKEs.png)

Comment: okay, next question: how are you currently setting the text? (Such as "coolio" or, "sure thing mon")

Comment: @Mr_Skid_Marks I'm not sure what you mean. This isn't an app I'm creating, it's a theme for an app (EvolveSMS) to be exact. The text is `@+id/body`. It's the same TextView for both. I'm not sure how it's differentiated.

Answer (score 1):

Use a

```
<LinearLayout> </LinearLayout>
```

with the orientation set as horizontal inside the table row item. put the textview and image inside the LL.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp" 
             android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:text="TextView" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Like that.

becomes: http://puu.sh/6GNRT.jpg

Comment: Which table row? Both of them?

Comment: Which textview? I can't put `@+id/body` in there twice.

Comment: Please don't leave me. I'm going insane.

Comment: You have a tablelayout then i presume you define the layout of the table row? put the linear layout in it, then drag them inside the linear layout instead?

Comment: Check edit, added example code, obviously it's not exactly styled like yours but it shows how to have them side by side

Comment: [What I got](http://pastebin.com/Pqm1ZjYT) [What it looks like](http://i.imgur.com/FVOi19S.png)

Comment: I just added the rest of the xml in my activity for you to look at, play around with it in a separate xml file and learn it. If you still cant resolve it, i fear you might need to slow down and read some more guides and xml and layout! :) Hope that helps.